# Data structure to save pixel data

Tags: java, swing, data-structures, 2d

I am writing a small game in which the player is controlling a small ball (can move vertically and horizontally). When the ball is moving, a line is drawn on its path.

I am using a LinkedList to save the position of the pixels (every time the ball moves the x and y coordinates are saved in the LinkedList)
I am storing objects of Pixel in the LinkedList (just made a simple class Pixel with int x,y and a getter for each)

```
p.add(new Pixel(x,y));
```

In my paint method every pixel of the line is then painted via a for-loop

```
 for (int i = 0; i < p.size(); i++)
            g.drawOval(p.get(i).getX(), p.get(i).getY(),1,1);
```

This is working well, but now I want to implement another feature and I can't figure out how to do this with the data structure I am using:

If the ball does reach the border of the map and the line does divide the map into 2 parts, one of these parts should be filled with a color.

I am not sure if this is even possible with my approach.
Anyone an idea what data structure I could use and I am also not sure if
using drawOval is the best way to do this. Anyone an idea?

Comment: Take a look at the [Path2D](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Path2D.html) class.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is very much can be in fact lot of research has already been done in this area, you need to look into `Polygon Clipping` techniques to achieve what you want and to answer your question of how to fill it with color, well once you are able to get the co-ordinates of the polygon to be clipped you can implement either of `Polygon Filling` method(floodfill) to fill it.Now filling so many pixel is also a memory consuming task there are many ways to overcome this memory leak situations but that you need not worry right now.Here are some links which might help you.
[Computer Graphics - Clipping](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/grads/h/Hao-wei.Hsieh/Haowei.Hsieh/mm.html)
[Solid Polygon Clipping Techniques](https://www.siggraph.org/education/materials/HyperGraph/scanline/clipping/spcl.htm)  PS: Are you making game like [JezzBall](http://onemorelevel.com/game/jezzball)